# Show error when C# numericUpDown is being changed to a value less than it's minimum value

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer, numericupdown

I have a **numericUpDown** in my C#.NET windows form and I have set it's minimum value to 5. Now I can't go below 5 using the numericUpDown button. But I also want to show an error message if user tries to reduce this value below 5. How do I do that?

The workaround that I did for this was like this:
I set the minimum value to 4 and if the value goes to 4 I am showing the error. But this is not a potentially good solution as it may result into some problems in future.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the control is working properly you cannot go below the minimum value. This behavior is as designed. It is better to visually disable the down button when the value is the minimum value, eliminating the need for any error messages. One can also add a tooltip that states the minimum value explicitly. Trying to work around the functionality as OP noted may lead to ending up with invalid data when input is being processed.

Comment: I agree with you. But as per the design, I specifically want to show a message when the value is being reduced than the minimum requirement. Is there any way by which we can know the numericUpDown is going down that the minimum value?

Comment: The only other way I can think of is trying to intercept the click event on the down arrow, should still happen even with a disabled control.